# No resource found that matches the given name in main.xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I was doing android programming to create BroadcastReceiver to intercept custom intent. I was continuously getting the same error every time. `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/ action_settings').`

I ve read all the answers here and changed my code accordingly and added a resource in **strings.xml** file as

```
"<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>"
```

The problem should be fixed but still m on the zeroth square and same error is coming again.

I ve added the fourth line of  tag in strings.xml file...i.e. `android:title="@string/action_settings"/>`, i m getting the error despite creating a resource in strings.xml file.

i will be very grateful to anyone helping. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post strings.xml and layout and also clear project

Comment: Try clear the project first. Next, check your imports for `Android.R` instead of your Project's `R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow some step. such as

1. Replace your project package instead of Android.R. for example , com.exaple.helloworld (your package)
2. delete your gen and bin folder
3. Clean your your project.Project=>Clean.

   and 4. Finally Restart your eclipse.

Hope fully, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your res/values/strings.xml and have a look if there is `<string name="action_settings"></string>` value.